# cocos2d CCLayer.m UIAccelerometer is deprecated warning

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm not actually using the accelerometer in my app, but this warning is the only one I get during the build process. I'd like to correct it or eliminate it. This warning directs me to the CCLayer.m cocos2d original files. There a 4 warnings about the UIAccelerometer deprecations.

(LINES 91 & 93 is where the warnings start) ! UIAccelerometer is deprecated in iOS 5.0 - UIAccelerometer has been replaced by the CoreMotion framework

```
    85:-(void) setIsAccelerometerEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
    86:{
    87: if( enabled != isAccelerometerEnabled_ ) {
    88:     isAccelerometerEnabled_ = enabled;
    89:     if( isRunning_ ) {
    90:         if( enabled )
    91:             [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
    92:         else
    93:             [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
    94:     }
    95: }
    96:}
```

When I dig deeper into the warnings it brings me deeper into the UIAccelerometer.h UIKit

Have others had this problem? How to deal with it? Should I just ignore it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, Justin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cocos2d-iphone as of version 2.1 has not been updated to be fully compatible with iOS 7.

As far as  accelerometer is concerned you can safely comment out all references to / uses of UIAccelerometer. If you do need accelerometer in your app use [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Alternatively you can use Kobold2D whose [github version](https://github.com/kobold2d/Kobold2D) includes the necessary fixes to cocos2d-iphone.

Comment: Stefen, does the 2.1 installer embed the iOS7 fixes for cocos2d? I just want to diff your take at it and my current take ... for completeness sake :).

Comment: Commenting out all references did the job! My next project I'd be interested in working with Kobold2D. Would Kobold2D replace cocos2d during development? Kobold2D have templates? I enjoyed and used 'Learn cocos2d Game Development' during my learning process. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally not the biggest fan of how Kobold2d "solved" the issue.  They're wrapping the code with pragmas that disable the warning.  Personally, I'd prefer to offer that it's better to replace the deprecated code with CoreMotion class.

To maintain the usability of a singleton class; use this answer: [How do I initialize CMMotionManager globaly to be used by different classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529224/how-do-i-initialize-cmmotionmanager-globaly-to-be-used-by-different-classes)
then in CCLayer.h at line 32 import MotionManagerSingleton.h
Next in CCLayer.m replace everything that looks like UIAccelerometer with the new call to this class and it works quite well.